# access pyspark in HUE notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hue

i am trying to access pyspark session in AWS EMR Hue notebook but getting following error:

The Spark session could not be created in the cluster: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:144) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:928) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:937) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) YARN Diagnostics:

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.